# Looping through a series of GET requests

Tags: javascript, loops, get

I have a get request that looks for a specific ID within a tree, and then pulls back the value from that ID. I need to loop through a series of these get requests, each with a similar ID (each ID increases in value by one).

I have created a standard loop using hard coded values but I'm struggling to set the variable based on dynamic values coming out of the tree.

For example, I can set a variable like this:

```
var cars = [entry.get('sub_menu.sub_menu_link.0.title'), entry.get('sub_menu.sub_menu_link.1.title'), entry.get('sub_menu.sub_menu_link.2.title')];
```

This grabs all the values from these areas of the tree.

But I don't know how many of these there will be so I can't hard code it in this way. I need to be able to replace 0, 1 and 2 in those values with a loop that adds a new get request and increases the integer between `"link."` and `".title"` each time.

Expected result would be to add as many get requests in to the variable as it finds, with the integer increased for each request, until it finds no more.

Full example code with hard coded get requests is below (which won't actually work because the tree isn't being pulled in. For example purposes only):

```
Query.fetch()
      .then(function success(entry) {
            var subMenu = [entry.get('sub_menu.sub_menu_link.0.title'), entry.get('sub_menu.sub_menu_link.1.title'), entry.get('sub_menu.sub_menu_link.2.title')];
            var text = "";
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < subMenu.length; i++) {
                text += subMenu[i] + "<br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("subMenu-container").innerHTML = text;
        }, 
        function error(err) {
            // err object
        });
```

Comment: What does `entry.get` return, and is `entry.get` synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: Does `entry` give you any way to tell how many `sub_menu.sub_menu_link.X.title` there are? Or a way to know whether `get` found one (for instance, by returning `null` or similar if not found)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering based on three assumptions:

1. `entry.get` is synchronous
2. `entry.get` returns `null` or `undefined` if it couldn't get the string matching the argument we pass it
3. Although your code is using promises, you want to keep it to ES5-level language features (not ES2015+)

See inline comments:

```
Query.fetch()
    .then(function success(entry) {
        // Loop getting titles until we run out of them, put them in `titles`
        var titles = [];
        var title;
        while (true) { // Loop until `break;`
            // Use string concat to include the value of `titles.length` (0, 1, ...) in the string
            title = entry.get('sub_menu.sub_menu_link.' + titles.length + '.title');
            if (title === null || title === undefined) {
                break;
            }
            titles.push(title);
        }
        // Use `Array.prototype.join` to join the titles together with <br> in-between
        document.getElementById("subMenu-container").innerHTML = titles.join("<br>");
    }, function error(err) {
        // Handle/report error
    });
```